# What does this mean in a java code? Is the first time I've seen it:

Tags: java

I would like to know what does this return statement mean since I have never seen it:

```
    static int max(int a, int b) { 

         return (a > b)? a : b; 
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a ternary operator basicly if a > b then return a else b